# Does Xamarin's C# version support depend on Android API level?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm a former Android Java developer thinking about getting back into mobile apps using Xamarin and C#. When using the Java SDK, some language and standard API features require a certain minimum Android SDK version. For example, [some Java 8 features require API 24](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).

Is something similar true of Xamarin apps? For example, Xamarin only used to support C# 6, but I think now it supports at least C# 8. Would my apps need to target a certain minimum Android version in order to use C# 8 features? If so, what Android versions are required for each language version?

Something I didn't originally ask, because I didn't know to ask, is whether the answer changes depending on whether I use Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin native. There was a good answer here addressing this, but the author was bullied into deleting it.

Comment: If Android API 24 is required for Java 8 features, then the same is true when using Xamarin.Android. Xamarin.Android is basically a C# wrapper around the Android SDK, so that you can instantiate and call into types in the Android SDK from C# code, in addition to bringing in much of the .NET framework, via Mono, so you can use .NET APIs in your Xam.Android project. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/xamarin/what-is-xamarin

Comment: Fair enough, I did not express that as well as I should have, but this does come into play when you are making bindings to Android libraries, i.e. if you are binding a library that uses Java 8 features, you will have to make sure your android binding library builds against at least API 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The Android API version is completely separate from the C# version.